# Get ajax response change old data to new data but echo function always taking same value how to fix

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'<?php echo site_url; ?>', data:{skills:skills,location:location}, dataType:'json' 
            var append = '';
            for(i = 0; i < msg.candidates.length; i++){
                var candidate = msg.candidates[i];
                var idd = candidate.candidate_id;
                if (idd > 0) {
                    var can = '<?php echo generate_token("'+idd+'"); ?>';
                    //alert(can);
                }
                append += '<tr role="row" class="odd req_list" data-hid="<?php echo generate_token("'+candidate.candidate_id+'"); ?>" onclick="get_candidate_detail(this,<?php echo "'+candidate.candidate_id+'"; ?>)">';
                append += '<td><?php echo "'+candidate.candidate_id+'"; ?></td>';
                append += '<td><?php echo "'+candidate.can_job_title+'"; ?></td>';
                append += '<td><?php echo "'+candidate.can_city+'"; ?></td>';
                append += '<td><?php echo date_mdy_format("'+candidate.vms_vc_can_updated_date+'"); ?></td>';
                append += '</tr>';

            }
            datatable.clear();
            datatable.draw();
            $('#op-table > tbody').html(append);  });
```

`generate_token()` function always takes the same value. How do I generate the correct token value. Sorry for the English, it is not my native language.

Comment: check your code first , your first php starting tag does not closes , before the another started

Comment: Yes i fix but still not working.

Comment: you **can't** execute php in js

Comment: What is the solution? please help me

Comment: I can't understand, how above code could possibly work, But if generate_token() gets always the same value, maybe you can put code for this function here? Any js console and PHP errors would be good to see as well.

Comment: Thx. I fix that issue convert html format did in controller itself.